# two table view in one view controller, swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview

My view controller has two table views. The askTable works, but bidTable doesn't work. No error comes out.

Here is what it prints. The array exactly contains the elements I want. Not sure what I did wrong or miss for bidTable. Also, wondering why "Hi" is never printed too.

```
askPriceArray: []
bidPriceArray: []
bid: 0 
Above repeat several times
askPriceArray: []
bidPriceArray: ["21"]
ask: 0
askPriceArray: []
bidPriceArray: ["21", "212"]
ask: 0
askPriceArray: ["21"]
bidPriceArray: ["21", "212"]
ask: 1
```

---

```
import UIKit 
class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var bidTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var askTable: UITableView! 
    var askPriceArray = [String]()
    var bidPriceArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.bidTable.dataSource = self
    self.bidTable.delegate = self
    self.askTable.dataSource = self
    self.askTable.delegate = self
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
.....insert elements to arrays from Parse..........
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("askPriceArray: \(self.askPriceArray)")
    print("bidPriceArray: \(self.bidPriceArray)")

    if tableView == self.askTable {
        print("ask: \(askPriceArray.count)")
        return askPriceArray.count
    } else {
        print("bid: \(bidPriceArray.count)")
        return bidPriceArray.count
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.askTable{
        let cell:DetailAskTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("askCell") as! DetailAskTableViewCell
        cell.askPriceAndQuantity.text = self.askPriceArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        print("Hi")
        let cell:DetailBidTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bidCell") as! DetailBidTableViewCell
        cell.bidPriceAndQuantity.text = self.bidPriceArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Are you reloading both tableviews when you setup your data?

Comment: I forgot to reload the bidTable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you are reloading *both* `UITableViews` after you have retrieved your data from Parse.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot to reload the bidTable. Thanks again